# Rails 3.2.2 no working with css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have a problem. I am doing a program in Ruby on Rails 3.2.2, but the page index.html.erb
no link to the stylesheet located in app/assets/stylesheets/welcome.css.scss

This is my page index localhost:3000/welcome/index

```
<h1>Bienvenido al curso de Ruby on Rails 3</h1>
<h2>Tutor: <%= @tutor %></h2>
<p>Esta es mi primera vista</p>    
<footer>
  <p>By : <%= @tutor %></p>
</footer>
```

Source Code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>HelloWorld</title

      <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />

      <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
    <meta content="Jhnt5tNWpHa2lbZhPDSSwPJqdtPp94m9/ZrzZaA9054=" name="csrf-token" />
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Bienvenido al curso de Ruby on Rails 3 </h1>
    <h2>Tutor: Código Facilito</h2>
    <p>Esta es mi primera vista</p>

<footer>
  <p>By : Código Facilito</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>   


<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The page  app/assets/stylesheets/welcome.css.scss  no is loaded in the source code 
Only is loaded app/assets/stylesheets/aplication.css

```
application_controller.rb

Layout    
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>HelloWorld</title

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/welcome.css.scss?body=1">

  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>

File application.css
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require welcome
 *= require_tree .
*/
```

Comment: Add this line to layout and and it worked   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/welcome.css.scss?body=1">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't how you include CSS files in Rails, for many reasons.

First, your path is wrong. You cannot directly link to `/assets/*`, because that's not the URL that will be used in production. The assets will be compiled, minified and finger printed. You need to use `asset_path`, or your paths to your assets will break when you deploy your application in production.

Secondly, the file served to the browser no longer has the `scss` extension. It will be a `.css` file.

Thirdly, you shouldn't be manually adding `?body=1` to your stylesheet. Rails will do that for you, when appropriate, provided you include your stylesheets correctly.

There are two ways to do this:

First, and probably what you're after, is to require the extra CSS file inside application.css. That's what it's for, it's a manifest for specifying what other CSS files to include. Do this by adding the following to application.css, or by modifying the existing `require` statements in that file to include an extra `require welcome` line:

```
/**
 *= require welcome
 */
```

The second way is to just directly include the file, but using the Rails helpers to get the path and filename correct:

```
<%= stylesheet_include_tag 'welcome' %>
```

Either way wil work.

Comment: friend <%= stylesheet_include_tag 'welcome' %> worked   /**
 *= require welcome
 */ not worked

Comment: I uploaded the file  application.css  to my question